# Overlaying a JFrame with a drawn image on a video player built on JMF

Tags: java, jframe, awt, jmf

I am building a traffic simulator by making video player which is supposed to interact with a traffic light simulator and i need to insert a frame of the traffic light onto the video being played from the machine. I have just drawn the traffic light onto the frame using JPanel and have made sure the frame is created after the player is initialized. But the problem is that they still don't overlay on top of each other after doing the various setAlwaysOnTop() or toFront() methods. I want the frame to come over the video player after some time and then disappear. But as soon as the frame is loaded, it minimizes the video. Please help me out.

Below is the code.

```
class MediaPlayer extends Frame implements ActionListener,ControllerListener,ItemListener
{

    Player player;
    Component vc, cc;
    Graphics2D traffic;
    int x,y,w,h;
    Time boss = new Time(0);
    //  boolean first = false, loop = false;

    MediaPlayer (String title) throws IOException
    {
        super (title);
        toFront();
        GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] devices = graphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices();
        if (devices[0].isFullScreenSupported()) {
            setUndecorated(true);
            setVisible (true);
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            x = (5*screenSize.width)/8;
            y = screenSize.height/2;
            w = 35;
            h = 50;
            setSize(screenSize);
            devices[0].setFullScreenWindow(this);
            validate();
            if (player != null)
                player.close ();

            try
            {
                player = Manager.createPlayer (new MediaLocator ("file:C:\\Documents and Settings\\User\\My Documents\\Downloads\\Fig21_06_07\\Fig21_06_07\\bailey.mpg"));
                if (player == null)
                {
                    System.out.println ("Trouble creating a player.");
                    return;
                }
                player.addControllerListener (this);
                System.out.println("asking for prefetch");
                player.prefetch ();
                setSize(screenSize);
                toFront();
                boolean flag = true;
                Time initial = player.getMediaTime(); 
                do {//  
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                    frame.toBack();

                    int he = 50, wi = 35;
                    //int x = 400, y = 400;
                    frame.setUndecorated(true);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                    frame.setLocation(x,y); 
                    frame.setSize(wi,he);
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                    ShapesJPanel tr = new ShapesJPanel();
                    tr.setSize(100,100);
                    tr.setBounds(0, 0,100,100);
                    tr.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                    tr.x = 0;
                    tr.y = 0;
                    tr.w = 100;                     
                                        tr.h1 = 100;
                    frame.add(tr);
                    validate();
                    pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    setVisible(true);
                    toFront();
                    x = (5*screenSize.width)/8;
                    y = screenSize.height/2;
                    w = 15;
                    h = 20;
                    setSize(screenSize);
                    boss = initial;
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    int i = 0;
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis()-start < 5000)
                    {
                    }
                    Time blah = player.getMediaTime();
                    boss = blah;
                    player.stop();
                    long restart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis()-restart < 5000)
                    {
                    }
                    boss = initial;
                    player.setMediaTime (blah);
                    player.start();
                    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis()-start < 5000)
                    {
                    }
                    player.setMediaTime (initial);
                    player.prefetch();
                    setSize(screenSize);
                    flag = false;
                }while(true);
            }
            catch (java.io.IOException e2)
            {
                System.out.println (e2);
                return;
            }
            catch (NoPlayerException e2)
            {
                System.out.println ("Could not find a player.");
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void controllerUpdate (ControllerEvent e)
    {
        // A ControllerClosedEvent is posted when player.close is
        // called.  If there is a visual component, this component must
        // be removed.  Otherwise, this visual component appears
        // blanked out on the screen. (To be consistent, we do the same
        // thing for the control panel component.)
        //
        // Note: This problem occurs when run under JMF 2.1 Windows and
        //       SDK 1.3 on a Windows 98 SE platform.

        if (e instanceof ControllerClosedEvent)
        { 
            if (vc != null)
            {
                remove (vc);
                vc = null;
            }

            if (cc != null)
            {
                remove (cc);
                cc = null;
            }

            return;
        }

        if (e instanceof EndOfMediaEvent)
        {
            player.setMediaTime(new Time(0));
            player.start();
            return;
        }

        if (e instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent)
        {
            System.out.println("Prefetch occured..");
            player.start ();
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            player.getVisualComponent().setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
            player.getVisualComponent().setMinimumSize(screenSize);
            player.getVisualComponent().setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
            return;
        }

        if (e instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent)
        {
            System.out.println("player realized..");
            vc = player.getVisualComponent ();

            if (vc != null){
                Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(). getScreenSize();
                vc.setMinimumSize(screenSize);
                vc.setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
                add (vc); 
            }
            pack ();

        }

    }

    public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint (g);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int wi = screenSize.width;
        int he = screenSize.height;
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.fillRect (0, 0, wi, he);
        // Call overridden Frame superclass paint method.  That method
        // will call each contained container and component (including
        // the control panel component) paint method.
    }

    // Eliminate control panel component flicker by preventing frame
    // background from being cleared.

    public void update (Graphics g)
    {
        paint (g);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        new MediaPlayer ("Road Simulator");
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like AWT, not Swing - if so, please edit the tags

Comment: Why you mixing both Swing and AWT. Do try to use JWindow instead of JFrame, might be that won't show such behaviour.

Comment: @gagandeep the reason im mixing them is because i wanted to make the video player but all the online support i see teaches us to do so in this format only. I shall try but since this has past my deadline and i have a new project to do i shall try this and let you know.

Comment: @Swap0 : Wish I could help on this simulation things, but seems like my knowledge is too short for that. But I hope you succeed in this endeavour of yours :-)

Comment: There's to much unresolved code that don't allow to properly test your sample :(.

Comment: Try to put the vc component in the main JFrame and then add the traffic light transparent JPanel on top of that vc component in the same JFrame.